# How to adjust layout when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I would like to adjust/re-size the layout when the soft-keyboard activated, as below:

**Before and After:**

[image][image]

---

Found couple resources in SO:

1. [How to keep all fields and texts visible while the soft keyboard is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493506/how-to-keep-all-fields-and-texts-visible-while-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown)
2. [android soft keyboard spoils layout when appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136891/android-soft-keyboard-spoils-layout-when-appears)
3. [Adjust layout when soft keyboard is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on)

---

But the questions & answers are rather ambiguous, here's the question with clearer picture of what I want.

**Requirements:**

- It should work on phone with any screen sizes.
- Noticed that the margin/padding space at "FACEBOOK" and "Sign Up for
  Facebook" has changed before and after.
- No scroll view is involved.

Comment: It is also worth remembering that resizing doesn't work in full screen (`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen`), as per this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509285/1307690

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Just add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml where you declare this particular activity and this will adjust the layout resize option.

[image]

some source code below for layout design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="FaceBook"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="username" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Log In" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sign up for facebook"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 That simple? Any extra conditions? What was the image you posted about?

Comment: friends just to show alignparentbottom="true" if the screen not adjusted properly ..hence i placed that image friend

Comment: Very good answer indeed. Thanks for the help, pal. Glad you'd came.

Comment: Friend it seems that only the TextView with "Sign up for facebook" adjusted itself when softkeyboard activated, others remain no change. I hope others get to adjust as well. Any workaround? And The whole layout should be at center before keyboard was activated,

Comment: friend only the bottom content can be adjusted using the resize option. you create the above layout as centered and place the bottom with some bottom margin to look centered ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29519/discussion-between-captain-america-and-roylee)

Comment: You can make a trick, write custom view, and it will work exactly like facebook app works (I guess they implemented custom view as well)

Comment: Is there a way to give some extra padding when it does adjustResize? Currently it resizes so that the bottom of the text cursor aligns EXACTLY with bottom of screen. I want to have extra 5dp gap below text cursor visible.

Comment: Hello @VenkateshS
Do you have any idea how to do it using constraints layout?
I have tried your solution but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Roylee To make whole layout keep centered your 1. outermost layout must be match_parent in height and width,Linear Layout and android:layout_gravity  = "center_vertical" inside it make a liner layout and make it cent android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" This will align the layout according to screen size always.

Answer (score 47):

This question has beeen asked a few years ago and "Secret Andro Geni" has a good base explanation and "tir38" also made a good attempt on the complete solution, but alas there is no complete solution posted here.
I've spend a couple of hours figuring out things and here is my complete solution with detailed explanation at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="facebook"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email or Phone"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Log In"
                android:onClick="login" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:id="@+id/footerLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:text="Sign Up for Facebook"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpButton"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
                        android:text="\?"
                        android:onClick="help" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And in **AndroidManifest.xml**, don't forget to set:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

on the `<activity>` tag that you want such layout.

**Thoughts:**

I've realized that `RelativeLayout` are the layouts that span thru all available space and are then resized when the keyboard pops up.

And `LinearLayout` are layouts that don't get resized in the resizing process.

That's why you need to have 1 `RelativeLayout` immediately after `ScrollView` to span thru all available screen space. And you need to have a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` else your insides would get crushed when the resizing occurs. Good example is "headerLayout". If there wouldn't be a `LinearLayout` inside that `RelativeLayout` "facebook" text would get crushed and wouldn't be shown.

In the "facebook" login pictures posted in the question I've also noticed that the whole login part (mainLayout) is centered vertical in relation to the whole screen, hence the attribute:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

on the `LinearLayout` layout. And because mainLayout is inside a `LinearLayout` this means that that part does't get resized (again see picture in question).

Comment: Works like a charm!! but footer is stick to bottom of the layout which is not looking nice. how can I avoid footer stick to bottom! instead if I wanna give some margin to footer so that layout looks good. I made some changes by giving layout_margin attribute to relative layout of the footer but with this it is covering last half of the Edit Text. Plz help me out.

Comment: In _RelativeLayout_ with _@+id/footerLayout_ you have a _LinearLayout_ that has this attribute: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This makes it stick to the bottom.

Comment: ya, keeping in mind that, i asked you how to do arrangements of the footer components that should have bottom margin at least 10dp or 15dp

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I just tested this myself by giving `android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"` to _footerLayout_ and then _RelativeLayout_ that is holding _textView2_ and _helpButton_. In both cases _helpButton_ gets crushed (even without the marginBottom attribute). In no way _editText1_ or _editText2_ ever gets crushed, because they're inside a _LinearLayout_. Did you maybe set margin on any other Layout (not only _footerLayout_)? Try from scratch if you're getting nowhere! You could also play with `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Instead of giving marginBottom attribute to other layouts,Just Removed android:paddingTop="10dp" and added android:paddingBottom="10dp" to the RelativeLayout of the ScrollView's Child. And got the expected result. Thank You @Yani2000

Comment: May I ask what my answer is missing? Your solution contains a lot of unneeded layout nesting.

Comment: @tir38 Essentially your answer is not missing a thing, but it's not 100% complete and devs like to have a complete answer that they can adjust to their needs. Therefore I made a complete working layout that resembles the above Facebook behavior. What probably bugs you are those additional `LinearLayout` elements. Like I already mentioned in **Thoughts**, if you have a small screen device your text would get crushed. I would suggest you try to make a replica of that Facebook behavior yourself (you can use my values) and try to improve my answer with your findings in your answer.

Comment: @tir38 Maybe there's an XML attribute I'm missing that doesn't crush text on resize?

Comment: @Yani2000 fair enough =)

Comment: "And LinearLayout are layouts that don't get resized in the resizing process." - this is a really helpful information.

Answer (score 36):

Add this line in your Manifest where your Activity is called

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

or

you can add this line in your `onCreate`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: You should never use both `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`. These are different modes. Read more about them here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/1738090
And here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Answer (score 30):

**It can work for all kind of layout.**

1. add this to your activity tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

for example:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityLogin"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

2. add this on your layout tag in **activitypage.xml** that will change its position.

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

and

> android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Comment: This answer provides better information on how to make any layout work.

Answer (score 14):

Android Developer has the right answer, but the provided source code is pretty verbose and doesn't actually implement the pattern described in the diagram.

Here is a better template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- stuff to scroll -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <!-- footer -->

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Its up to you to decide what views you use for the "scrolling" and "footer" parts. Also know that you probably have to set the `ScrollView`s
[fillViewPort](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) .

Comment: Tried following your solution but using two `LinearLayout`s instead of the Frame and Relative, but all views are still on top of eachother.

Answer (score 12):

This makes it possible to show any wanted layout previously hidden by the keyboard.

Add this to the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Surround your root view with a ScrollView, preferably with scrollbars=none. The ScrollView will properly not change any thing with your layout except be used to solve this problem.

And then set fitsSystemWindows="true" on the view that you want to make fully shown above the keyboard.
This will make your EditText visible above the keyboard, and make it possible to scroll down to the parts below the EditText but in the view with fitsSystemWindows="true".

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

For example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        ...

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want to show the full part of fitsSystemWindows="true" view above the keyboard in the moment the keyboard appears, you will need some code to scroll the view to the bottom:

```
// Code is in Kotlin

setupKeyboardListener(scrollView) // call in OnCreate or similar


private fun setupKeyboardListener(view: View) {
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
        if (Math.abs(view.rootView.height - (r.bottom - r.top)) > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            onKeyboardShow()
        }
    }
}

private fun onKeyboardShow() {
    scrollView.scrollToBottomWithoutFocusChange()
}

fun ScrollView.scrollToBottomWithoutFocusChange() { // Kotlin extension to scrollView
    val lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1)
    val bottom = lastChild.bottom + paddingBottom
    val delta = bottom - (scrollY + height)
    smoothScrollBy(0, delta)
}
```

Full layout example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/statisticsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:background="@drawable/some"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/some"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/authenticationLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/statisticsLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameEditTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/usernameEditTextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/passwordEditTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is what gave me the desired results I wanted...thanks

Answer (score 8):

For those using **ConstraintLayout**,  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` will not work.

What you can do is use a [soft keyboard listener](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent), set constraints of the views from **bottom to bottom** of the upper views, then set a vertical bias for each view (as a positional percentage between constraints) to a horizontal guideline (also positioned by percentage, but to the parent).

For each view, we just need to change `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` to `@+id/guideline` when the keyboard **is shown**, programmatically of course.

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginLogo"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />


        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginFields"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".15"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginLogo">

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".25"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginFields"/>
```

Generally a soft keyboard takes up no more than 50% of the height of the screen. Thus, you can set the guideline at 0.5.

```
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

Now programmatically, when the keyboard is **not shown**, we can set all the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` back to parent, vice-versa.

```
            unregistrar = KeyboardVisibilityEvent.registerEventListener(this, isOpen -> {
            loginLayout.startAnimation(AnimationManager.getFade(200));
            if (isOpen) {
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginLogo, R.id.guideline, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID, -1, "235:64", 0.15f,
                        63, 0, 63, 0);
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginFields, R.id.guideline, -1, R.id.loginLogo, null, 0.15f,
                        32, 0, 32, 0);
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginBtn, R.id.guideline, -1, R.id.useFingerPrintIdText, null, 0.5f,
                        32, 0, 32, 0);
            } else {
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginLogo, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID, -1, "235:64", 0.15f,
                        63, 0, 63, 0);
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginFields, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID, -1, R.id.loginLogo,null, 0.15f,
                        32, 0, 32, 0);
                setSoftKeyViewParams(loginBtn, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID, -1, R.id.useFingerPrintIdText,null, 0.25f,
                        32, 0, 32, 0);
            }
        });
```

Call this method:

```
    private void setSoftKeyViewParams(View view, int bottomToBottom, int topToTop, int topToBottom, String ratio, float verticalBias,
                                  int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
    viewParams.dimensionRatio = ratio;
    viewParams.bottomToBottom = bottomToBottom;
    viewParams.topToTop = topToTop;
    viewParams.topToBottom = topToBottom;
    viewParams.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    viewParams.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    viewParams.verticalBias = verticalBias;
    viewParams.setMargins(Dimensions.dpToPx(left), Dimensions.dpToPx(top), Dimensions.dpToPx(right), Dimensions.dpToPx(bottom));
    view.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
}
```

The important thing is to be sure to set the vertical bias in a way that would scale correctly when the keyboard is shown and not shown.

Comment: A simpler method is to wrap the ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView or a NestedScrollView. The calculations end up being too much of a work around. But your answer is great if a ScrollView would end up causing other issues

Answer (score 6):

Many answers are right. In `AndroidManifest` I wrote:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" // Optional, doesn't affect.
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

In my case I added a theme in `styles.xml`, but you can use your own:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <!--  Hide ActionBar -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

I noiced that if I use full-screen theme, resizing doesn't occur:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!--  Hide ActionBar -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!--  Hide StatusBar -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Also in my case `adjustResize` works, but `adjustPan` doesn't.

For **full-screen layouts** see a workaround in [Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible) or in https://gist.github.com/grennis/2e3cd5f7a9238c59861015ce0a7c5584.

Also https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/problem-solved-3-android-full-screen-view-translucent-scrollview-adjustresize-keyboard-b0547c7ced32 works, but it's StatusBar is transparent, so battery, clock, Wi-Fi icons are visible.

If you create an activity with File > New > Activity > Fullscreen Activity, where in code is used:

```
fullscreen_content.systemUiVisibility =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

you also won't achieve a result. You can use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in a root container, but StatusBar appears. So use workarounds from the first link.

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya, thanks! Notice, that if you then want to revert to normal mode (non-fullscreen), this workaround should be removed. I wasted many hours on it. In my case below layout I got a white space. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

In **Kotlin** or in **ConstraintLayout** you just add :

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

OR

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

Which state you need after activity launch, you can set from manifest.

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
      <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set these options in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourACtivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

The use of `adjustPan` is not recommended by Google because the user may need to close the keyboard to see all the input fields.

More info: [Android App Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Did you really try this? This is no different to `ajustNothing`

Comment: @Farid It might be because your screen is big enough so there's enough space. Also make sure you applied this to the right activity.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked with this line of code:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Just put it into onCreate method.
Best!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to also explain why this works.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line into Manifiest File:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy way in kotlin

In your fragment

```
requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
```

In your layout :

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it helped.

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.livewallpaper.profileview.loginact.Main2Activity">

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <EditText
        android:hint="enter here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="signup for App"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this in `manifest` file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Now the most important part!
Use theme like this in either `Activity` or `Application` tag.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

And the theme tooks like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

So I was missing the theme. Which made me frustrated all day.

Answer (score 1):

I use this Extended class frame 
And when I need to recalculate the height size onLayout I override onmeasure 
and subtract keyboardHeight using getKeyboardHeight()

My create frame who needs resize with softkeyboard

```
SizeNotifierFrameLayout frameLayout = new SizeNotifierFrameLayout(context) {
            private boolean first = true;

            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
                super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

                if (changed) {
                    fixLayoutInternal(first);
                    first = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getKeyboardHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
                boolean result = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
                if (child == actionBar) {
                    parentLayout.drawHeaderShadow(canvas, actionBar.getMeasuredHeight());
                }
                return result;
            }


        };
```

SizeNotifierFrameLayout

```
public class SizeNotifierFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public interface SizeNotifierFrameLayoutDelegate {
        void onSizeChanged(int keyboardHeight, boolean isWidthGreater);
    }

    private Rect                            rect            = new Rect();
    private Drawable                        backgroundDrawable;
    private int                             keyboardHeight;
    private int                             bottomClip;
    private SizeNotifierFrameLayoutDelegate delegate;
    private boolean                         occupyStatusBar = true;

    public SizeNotifierFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public Drawable getBackgroundImage() {
        return backgroundDrawable;
    }

    public void setBackgroundImage(Drawable bitmap) {
        backgroundDrawable = bitmap;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getKeyboardHeight() {
        View rootView = getRootView();
        getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        int usableViewHeight = rootView.getHeight() - (rect.top != 0 ? AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight : 0) - AndroidUtilities.getViewInset(rootView);
        return usableViewHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
    }

    public void notifyHeightChanged() {
        if (delegate != null) {
            keyboardHeight = getKeyboardHeight();
            final boolean isWidthGreater = AndroidUtilities.displaySize.x > AndroidUtilities.displaySize.y;
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (delegate != null) {
                        delegate.onSizeChanged(keyboardHeight, isWidthGreater);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setBottomClip(int value) {
        bottomClip = value;
    }

    public void setDelegate(SizeNotifierFrameLayoutDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setOccupyStatusBar(boolean value) {
        occupyStatusBar = value;
    }

    protected boolean isActionBarVisible() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (backgroundDrawable != null) {
            if (backgroundDrawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                if (bottomClip != 0) {
                    canvas.save();
                    canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() - bottomClip);
                }
                backgroundDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
                backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
                if (bottomClip != 0) {
                    canvas.restore();
                }
            } else if (backgroundDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable;
                if (bitmapDrawable.getTileModeX() == Shader.TileMode.REPEAT) {
                    canvas.save();
                    float scale = 2.0f / AndroidUtilities.density;
                    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
                    backgroundDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) Math.ceil(getMeasuredWidth() / scale), (int) Math.ceil(getMeasuredHeight() / scale));
                    backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
                    canvas.restore();
                } else {
                    int actionBarHeight =
                            (isActionBarVisible() ? ActionBar.getCurrentActionBarHeight() : 0) + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && occupyStatusBar ? AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight : 0);
                    int   viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - actionBarHeight;
                    float scaleX     = (float) getMeasuredWidth() / (float) backgroundDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    float scaleY     = (float) (viewHeight + keyboardHeight) / (float) backgroundDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    float scale      = scaleX < scaleY ? scaleY : scaleX;
                    int   width      = (int) Math.ceil(backgroundDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * scale);
                    int   height     = (int) Math.ceil(backgroundDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * scale);
                    int   x          = (getMeasuredWidth() - width) / 2;
                    int   y          = (viewHeight - height + keyboardHeight) / 2 + actionBarHeight;
                    canvas.save();
                    canvas.clipRect(0, actionBarHeight, width, getMeasuredHeight() - bottomClip);
                    backgroundDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
                    backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
                    canvas.restore();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        notifyHeightChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. When keyboard appears, you can scroll screen

[image]
[image]

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".signup.screen_2.SignUpNameAndPasswordActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

activity_sign_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".signup.screen_2.SignUpNameAndPasswordActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_24"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_24"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_24"
                android:id="@+id/lin_name_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:text="@string/name_and_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ts_16"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_full_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_44"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:hint="@string/email_address_hint"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ts_15"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_44"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ts_15"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_continue_and_sync_contacts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_44"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_selector"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/continue_and_sync_contacts"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ts_15"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_continue_without_syncing_contacts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_44"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/continue_without_syncing_contacts"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ts_15"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--RelativeLayout is scaled when keyboard appears-->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_24"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_24"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_learn_more_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/learn_more_syncing_contacts"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_alpha_70"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ts_13"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_learn_more_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/learn_more"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_alpha_70"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ts_13"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

rounded_border_edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#F6F6F6"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_activated="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#F6F6F6"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorGray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

btn_blue_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBlueLight"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorBlueLight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBlue"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorBlue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBlueAlpha"/>
            <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="@color/colorBlueAlpha"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case only this solution worked:

1. In Manifest:

   ```
     <activity
       android:name=".TTSpeech"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
       android:exported="false" />
   ```
2. In Activity call

> clearFocus();

on edittext.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin register below code in your activity

```
 WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize | Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan
```

I used a Relative Layout if you're using Constraint Layout, the above code will work code below