# How to set layout above soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, window-soft-input-mode

I have next xml layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/transfer_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_500"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/tv_money_type"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray_400">
                    </EditText>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/btn_transfer_select_receiver"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue_500" />

        </LinearLayout>          
</LinearLayout>
```

when i scroll down and click on editText - open softKeyBoard and layout resize, so i can see only editText field, and I need all last LinearLayout was above keyboard so user can see btn below editText.

here is my activity in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".acitivity.Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible">
        </activity>
```

i was trying to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but it looks like it doesn't work with scrollView...

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you mean main LinearLayout inside scrollView? or ScroollView?

Comment: You should set that in scrollview

Answer (score 1):

1) In AndroidManifest.xml use:

```
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

2) [Check this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16411103/4576879)

3) Or you can try this one:

```
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
```

If you need to open KeyBoard originally.

Hope it helps you.