# Show soft keyboard without changing views positions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

We are doing an app like Whatsapp, so we show an emoji panel or the soft keyboard. We are using adjustResize as we need to get the soft keyboard's height (in order to ensure that emoji panel has the same height as soft keyboard), everything works fine but, when changing from emoji panel to keyboard we see how the edittext goes to bottom and then goes up with the soft keyboard.

How could we do in order to fix the edittext while the soft keyboard is shown? I've thought about changing from adjustResize to adjustPan on the moment before the keyboard is shown, but then we are getting problems with measuring the keyboard's height (through the ViewTreeObserver).
Any idea about how could we solve that issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: im have similar problem, help me answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout with view into ScrollView and use adjustPan, in this way you can scroll content when the keyboard show's.

Or you can try:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```