# Button footer is not working when the input keyboard is visible

Tags: android, keyboard, soft-keyboard

I have an activity with a couple of `editText` in the top of the activity and two `buttons` that i have in a footer.

When I press one of the edit text the keyboard is shows up and the footer `adjustResize`. This is the behaviour that I want to have.

My problem is that when I try to press one of this `buttons` (when the keyboard is visible) the keyboard is hidden and the action to press the button is not working.

My question is, how can I keep the footer working when the keyboard is visible in the activity.

My activity in the manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.InitSessionActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

I've created my activity according to the solution of this answer:
[How to adjust layout when soft keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears)

My activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/screen"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/screen"
        android:id="@+id/ly_general"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/inputTextLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/edittextWithTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout">

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/footer" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/inputTextLayout"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/edittextWithTextInputLayout"
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_init_session"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_ed_email"
                android:layout_width="314dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_email"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white3"
                style="@style/edittextWithTextInputLayout"
                android:transitionName="@string/email"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_ed_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_init_session"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/secundary_foreground" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/inputTextLayout"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/edittextWithTextInputLayout"
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_ed_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Contraseña"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                style="@style/edittextWithTextInputLayout"
                android:transitionName="@string/password"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_ico_password"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_btn_enter"
                android:nextFocusUp="@+id/login_ed_email"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/secundary_foreground" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_tx_forgot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/secundary_foreground"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_13"
            android:text="@string/login_forgot_password"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/login_title_init_session"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_22"
            android:id="@+id/text_init_session"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_13"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_loycus_new"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Foter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundScreens"
        android:id="@+id/view"/>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/volver"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_folder_widht"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_folder_height"
        android:id="@+id/buttonComeBack"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selecto_come_back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:text="@string/enter"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_folder_widht"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_folder_height"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_green"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/login_loycus"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: keep your whole layout inside a scroll view and check

Comment: I've just updated the question with my xml. Yes, I have the layout inside of a scroll view and is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your footer as:-

```
<include layout="@layout/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Remove this from ScrollView

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Remove this from relative layout having id ly_general

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Add this to scrollview

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

EDIT:-

If you don't want to align your footer to bottom, then remove this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and adjust it wherever you want to place it on your UI.

Comment: Hi Nainal. I've tried your changes but the effect is the same. The footer is show with the keyboard but when I try to press the button, the keyboard is hide and the press button doesn't work. At this moment, the button come back at the down of the activity and, now I can press and work, but this is not the behaviour that I want. I need to be able to press the button when the keyboard is showed

Comment: i am not sure it will work or not ,try this in your onclick :-

Comment: if(view.hasFocus()){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }

Comment: which action you are taking in your button click

Comment: Something simple, go to another activity. Problem is that when I press button, keyboard desappear, button go down in the activity and don't do nothing

Comment: but earlier you said that now you can press and it worked

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've explained me bad. The button work when the keyboard is hide, but I want that work when the keyboard is show, too, and the footer is above of the keyboard. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your xml with a footer i wrote

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and everything seems to be working fine.
can you maybe explain the problem a bit more? or post your code/footer?

Comment: Hi Yuxal. I've updated my code with my footer xml. The footer is working fine and is showed with the keyboard. My problem is that if I try to press the button, the keyboard is hide and the press button is not working. That i want to do is can press the button footer while the keyboard is showed. You know what I mean??

Comment: Have you implemented onclicklistener on button?

Comment: Yes, because when the keyboard is not showed I can press the button and works

Comment: @S.P. Can you post a screenshot of the issue? it's hard to understand what's wrong