# Set adjustResize for full-screen mode

Tags: android, keyboard, fullscreen

How to set adjustResize for full-screen mode ?
I want to have button on bottom that can be moved up when keyboard is open.

These 3 flags and adjustResize in combination:
FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN and FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586564/layout-is-not-pushing-up-when-soft-keyboard-appears/47586628#47586628

Comment: I saw that, but it says NOTE: - fullscreen mode doesn't resize. So I am looking for appropriate way to have this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in Android, see this article: https://medium.com/@egek92/beaware-of-android-bug-5497-for-your-own-sake-19cf76abb7e5

and this question:

[Keyboard moves item of the Activity in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315541/keyboard-moves-item-of-the-activity-in-fragment)

Comment: the medium post seems removed, is the bug fixed? I'm still seeing the issue so asking.

Comment: you might want to check this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36986276 @AA_PV