# Resizing screen does not working when keyboard shows up

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to resize my layout to fit the screen when the keyboard appears, I followed the instructions provided here: [How to adjust layout when soft keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears)

But still does not seem to work, the only text that goes higher is "Welcome to ....", and if you lower my boxes (username, password, e-mail, full name) so that they would be hidden when the keyboard shows up so nothing happens even "welcome to ..." moves up.

I don't know what the problem might be here is my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".testLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logoLayout"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/nlogo">


            </ImageView>


        </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/logoLayout1"
                android:layout_below="@id/logoLayout"

                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/testUsernameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Username"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/testPasswordText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/testEmailText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/testFullNameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Full Name"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:text="Sign Up"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logoLayout1"
    android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:text="Welcome to ....."
                android:textSize="15sp" />



    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>




    </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".testLayout"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".registerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".loginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also does adjustResize work with constraintLayout as well!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" instead

Comment: nothing happens as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this will resize your screen

Add  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".testLayout">
```

and add android:layout_gravity="center" in RelativeLayout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: layout_gravity="center" is already in the RelativeLayout under id mainLayout and also i tried adding fitsSystemWindows="true" but still it's not resizing anything

Comment: android:gravity="center" is there in your code not android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: ah sorry that was my bad, i added that now its moving , but also the logo top is moving and the bottom text is still hidden and "Full Name" box as well, its not working as they described it , like in facebook layout.