# can not working windowsoftinputmode in android

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, responsive-design

I add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in mainfest file but can not any changes..

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Activitys.HomeActivity" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

**how to implement in android?**

[image]

so, please help me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, your question is unclear. I guess English is not your native language.

Comment: edit my question.

Comment: You may mean this way, check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust layout when soft keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears)

Comment: nothing changes bro...