Keyboard hides layout in Android 15
I have upgraded my project to Android 15. I am using scrollview with some edittexts. While I click on edittext, keyboard hides view behind in Android 15. I have enable enableEdgeToEdge() with onCreate function in the Activity.
When I use android:fitsSystemWindows="true" view does not hide behind the keyboard but statusbar color changed to white color.
How to change color for statusbar color with fitsSystemWindows = true?

Could you please provide more information: screenshot, gif, video, code etc.? Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears
and this doc https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility

Try out this function, it works for me.
fun Activity.setStatusBarColor(color: Int, isLightStatusBar: Boolean) {
    val window: Window = this.window

    // Set the status bar color
    window.statusBarColor = color

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        // For Android 11 and above
        val insetsController = window.insetsController
        if (insetsController != null) {
            insetsController.setSystemBarsAppearance(
                if (isLightStatusBar) WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS else 0,
                WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS
            )
        }
    } else {
        // For older versions
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (isLightStatusBar) {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        } else {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
        }
    }
}

Now, use the above mentioned function like this
// Example usage
        setStatusBarColor(
            color = getColor(R.color.your_status_bar_color),
            isLightStatusBar = true // Set to false if you want dark status bar icons
        )

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Hello @Vishal,
window.statusBarColor = color
this code is showing deprecated.

Also, custom color is not showing instead white color is showing.
